# Play store dowload count not updating correctly

Tags: google-play

I released an app 3 days ago on thursday night, today is sunday. The download count stayed for 2 days with only 1 downloads. I have read that it updates in 1-2 days. In fact it did update today and now it is showing only 10 but i don't think that is real because it has more than 210 ratings and also i can see real time users count on google analytics which is at least 30 in each moment and 5200 in total at this moment.

**Has anybody issued this before?**

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess i should answer my own question if it helps anybody in the same situation. After waiting some days in clueless mode(4-5) the count came where it should. I think it might have been a load or something because even Google Play Developer Console would not display the right count. Now it is updating daily